# Theme translation not applying

Tags: theme-development, themes, localization

I donwloaded and applied a theme to my WordPress 4.7.2 installation.

The site's locale specified in the admin settings is `it_IT` and the theme was not translated in this language so I'm trying to create a translation for the custom strings the theme uses.

So what I did was:

- Opened the `/wp-content/themes/thf/languages/thf.pot` file (`thf` being the theme's name) with POEdit
- Created a new it_IT translation and translated all the strings
- Saved the project. `/wp-content/themes/thf/languages/it_IT.po` and `/wp-content/themes/thf/languages/it_IT.mo` files were created
- Edited the `functions.php` adding the following.

.

```
function thf_setup() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'thf', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'thf_setup' );
```

But the strings won't translate. Looks like I don't need to define `WP_LANG` in `config.php` since I'm on WordPress 4.7.2 so I didn't edit that.

I also looked at other similar questions but they all point to either `load_theme_textdomain`, which I added, or `WP_LANG`, which I don't need.

Am I missing something else?
Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: double check your theme textdomain name and the names supplied to gettext helper functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was more trivial then expected.

The function `thf_setup()` was already defined and hooked in the theme's `functions.php` so I just added the `load_theme_textdomain` call to that function instead of declaring a new one (which would also be duplicated).